# Is there a way to force C preprocessor to evaluate macro arguments before the macro

Tags: c, macros

I have a number of macros in the form

```
#define F(A,B)   Some function of A and B
```

and for readability I would like to define arguments for these macros e.g.

```
#define C A,B
```

so that I can say

```
F(C)
```

but the preprocessor tries to expand F before C and complains that F needs 2 arguments. Is there a way to make it expand C before it expands F so that the error does not occur?

Comment: Oh my god you should never do this.

Comment: I do not understand some peoples obsession with the pre-processor. Just use it for simple stuff. The compiler is a lot better - it has the luxury of type safety for starters

Comment: If you need that, generate your C code from something else. Perhaps use some other preprocessor (e.g. `m4`  or `gpp`); it is not a job the the standard C preprocessor

Comment: @EdHeal Yeah, I agree. I even avoid non-macro variadic functions. Couldn't resist not to answer though.

Comment: lol 'for readability' in a macro question:)

Comment: @EdHeal not possible to do this with the compiler, its text manipulation at allow micro port definitions (where PORT name and bit number are needed if various combinations for different operations) to be done in 1 place. The is to make the code readable and maintainable. The alternative would be to define several functions (or macros) for each IO pin. This is the lesser of 2 evils.

Comment: @2501 yes its a bit messy but it worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use an intermediate macro that takes a variable number of arguments:

```
#define F1(A,B) 
#define F(...) F1(__VA_ARGS__)

#define C A,B

int main(void) {
    F(C)
    F(1,2)
    return 0;
}
```

This should compile. You will still get a compilation failure if you pass more or less than two arguments, or arguments that don't expand to exactly two arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Macro expansion (erroneously) does not trigger argument recount.  Therefore, any time macro expansion of a function invocation results in a different number of arguments, it must be forced to recount the number of arguments.

Use this pattern to force expansion and recount before invocation:

```
//Step 1: wrap the entire affected argument pack in parenthesis
#define mFn(A, ExpandingArgument) mFn1((A, ExpandingArgument))

//Step 2: intermediary layer without ## or # is required to actually expand
#define mFn1(...) mFn2(__VA_ARGS__)

//Step3: Paste the parenthesized arguments to final function identifier to trigger 
//       function like macro interpretation and invocation
#define mFn2(...) mFn3##__VA_ARGS__

//Step4: Implement the actual function as if the standard were written correctly
#define mFn3(A,B,C,...) //Do things
```